# Flat File Import!

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to import .csv .txt .xml and fixed length files into a mssql database. I would like to validate each files data before the import and map the data to columns in the database after the validation.

Could anyone please advise me of a project or a blog as a starting point? I would like to find a project the allows the uploads off all these file type even if in a fixed format to begin with. Anybody know of a project that could get me off to a good start?

I would appreciate any input or words of advice!

Comment: Although probably a lot more than you bargained for, SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) was designed to do just this. It's a beast though.

Comment: Check out filehelpers http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: @Derek +1 for filehelpers. I think you should post this as an answer instead of comment.

Comment: @Derek +1 for filehelpers as well.  Never heard of it.  Looks very helpful, no pun intended.

Comment: LINQ to CSV may fit your fancy as well. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx

Comment: if you don't want to use annotations, check this library <http://f2enum.codeplex.com/>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filehelpers is a nice lib http://www.filehelpers.com/.  I can probably dig up some examples.

Comment: Thanks this was a lot of help